# How did Max & Jack know of the sceptre before it was discovered?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-score

In *The Score*, Max explains how the sceptre was brought into the country hidden inside the leg of an antique piano. I presume the piano was only held up in the customs house due to the shipment being contaminated with termites. At the time when the sceptre was finally discovered by officials during the destruction of the piano, Jack had already been employed at the customs house.

How did he know about the sceptre's location before its discovery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the point here.

Max setup Jack into the job to keep an eye on the piano and the scepter. It was being smuggled into Montreal hidden in piano's leg. But then piano and other stuff was being confiscated by customs for being a bio hazard.

Max probably being into robbery and smuggling business had the info, which is not explained in movie.

Comment: So why the sceptre was hidden in the first place, where it came from and how Max got to know about it is never fully explained in the movie, I guess?

Comment: @Double M: Updated my answer. Please check.